# Correct calculation of assets profit and loss

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I would like to make some profit and loss calculations based on the market prices.

###### Scenario 1 (profit):

1. Given a crypto is worth `$1500`.
    I've made a purchase for `$100`.
    I've got `0.01666666666666572` (`formula: 100 / 1500`) of crypto asset.
2. Now a crypto price is worth `$1505.55`.
    I've decided to sell all of my crypto assets (`0.01666666666666572`) for actual price.
    Now I have `$100.37` (`formula: 0.01666666666666572 * 1505.55`).
   I've made `$0.37` (`formula: 100.37 - 100`) of profit.

**Question 1**: Is it calculated correctly ?

###### Scenario 2 (loss):

1. Given a crypto is worth `$1500`.
    I've made a purchase for `$100`.
    I've got `0.01666666666666572` (`formula: 100 / 1500`) of crypto asset.
2. Now a crypto price is worth `$1494.45`.
    I've decided to sell only a `$12` worth of crypto for actual price.
    `formula: 0.01666666666666572 * 1494.45` gives me `24.907499999998585` number, which I believe is totally wrong.

**Question 2**: How do I calculate a loss in that case ?
**Question 3**: How do I calculate how much assets I have now ?

Comment: If you are looking at actually modelling reality you will need to add transaction costs to both sides

Comment: @Alan - yeah you're right, but I've skipped that fees part on purpose (0% fees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number of units is wrong.  $\frac{100}{1500}\approx 0.0666666666667$.  You should not have the $1$.  Your multiplication to get the sale value in the profit case is also wrong.  If you multiply $0.0666666666666572 * 1494.45=99.63$ you will find you lost $0.37$

For question 3, you calculate the number of units you sell by dividing the number of dollars by the dollars/unit.  You then subtract that number of units from the number you started with.  As the price has not changed much, you should sell about $1/8$ of what you started with, leaving $7/8$

Comment: I'm trying to follow you guide: `100/1500 - 12/1494.45`, it get's me `0.05863695673993777`. Is that right?

Comment: It looks right to me.  I didn't check it in a calculator.

Comment: thank you for explanation and your time